# Typescript polymorphism: inference of return type for parent method which uses child property/method?

Tags: typescript, inheritance, polymorphism

I'm new to TypeScript and having a hard time with something. I have searched Google & SO comprehensively. The following code works with no errors, the problem is TS and the IDE are not aware of the correct return types, which defeats the purpose of the architecture.

```
class Data {
 schema: z.Schema<any>

  parse(): this["parse"] {
    return this.schema.parse({});
  }
}

class LoginData extends Data {
 schema = z.object({
    email: z.string(),
    password: z.string()
  })
}
```

```
const data = new LoginData().parse();
```

When adding the `parse` method directly to the `LoginData` class, TS is able to infer the return type correctly:

[image]

But when using the parent method directly, TS gets confused:

[image]

Comment: If you make it a public field, then you can: https://tsplay.dev/WPpPKW

Comment: Thank you caTS, what about for the second example? Is `Promise<this["parse"]>` valid? Trying it seems to return the schema object but not the parsed schema object.

Comment: What do you mean by that? Can you update your example in the post to include these changes?

Comment: Om updated the example, hopefully it makes sense. I can't post images so I included links.

Comment: `LoginData` doesn't have a `parse` method, though. Also, it should be `ReturnType<this["parse"]>`, right?

Comment: `LoginData` has `parse` through extending `Data`. I tried `ReturnType<this["parse"]>` and the value wen't back to `any`, which was the original issue. It sounds like this should be possible though? I need to understand the syntax deeper.

Comment: I think you'd have to use this? https://tsplay.dev/w8x2Vw

Comment: Oh shoot, even *better*: https://tsplay.dev/Nl2GXW

Comment: Wow - that is some crazy syntax but it works! Thank you so much. I do wonder why abstract properties/methods are not always inferred from the implementation though. I have a lot to learn about TS. Thank.

Comment: Now sure how to accept an answer from you?

Comment: Oh I'll write one now of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we do some trickery we can pass the child class to the parent class like this:

```
import z from "zod";

abstract class Data<T extends { schema: z.Schema<any> }> {
    abstract schema: T["schema"];

    parse(): z.infer<T["schema"]> {
        return this.schema.parse({});
    }
}

class LoginData extends Data<LoginData> {
    schema = z.object({
        email: z.string(),
        password: z.string(),
    });
}
```

Then in the parent class, we can get the schema with `T["schema"]` and use it however we'd like. Here, we're using it as the type of `schema`, and the return type of `parse`. This works since the type of `schema` in the parent class is now the same type of `schema` in the child class.

`z.infer` is a built-in type from Zod that gives us the parsed type from a schema.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/Nl2GXW)